# Does the html code in php file to be included in other files need to be wrapped in <html> tag?

Tags: php, html

I have a signin.php file that can be used in multiple web pages where users can sign in via the pop up window. This file includes

```
<?php
//some code to process submitted sign up form
?>

<div>
// some html code for the sign in pop up window
</div>
```

I want to include signin.php in other html page files. Do I need to wrap the html code above with !DOCTYPE html, html, head, or body tag? I tested it seems it works without these tags.
Thanks.

Comment: `I have tested it and it works...` so where is the issue and question? `PHP include` parses the content of the incldued file into the own file 1:1 server sided. and that server sided file is then passed on to the browser that requestiong the resource. So logically the incldued file is not allowed to have use tags that cause an invalid markup on the final parsed file.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No, if your going to just include the tags from another file then you don't need to put the `<html>` tag because if your code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div>
<?php include("hello.php")?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and in hello.php you just have an h1 tag with hello
it will get rendered as

```
<div>
<h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! so it looks like even there is no php code but only html code I can still name the file as .php and use "include" to reuse it.

Comment: @EvanW. yes, that is the best way to reuse html code in php

Comment: But you don't need to fully insert all php codes. You can also insert HTML codes. And to use a PHP code, just add the ```<?php``` and type the PHP code. After that, end the code with ```?>```